# Why is the usage of withDefault() method in Laravel Models giving 500 Server Error?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

The usage of the withDefault() on the relation method is giving Server Error problem. Why is this happening? Is there any cause of it? I believe I am syntactically correct.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products'; 


    public function category() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Category', 'id', 'category_id');
    }

    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\ProductImage', 'product_id', 'id')->withDefault();
    }
}
```

Without the usage of the withDefault() method, the page's running fine with the images showing but using this triggers server error.

Comment: A 500 will be accompanied by an error. Check your error_logs or change your settings to show all errors.

Comment: So, what does the error say?

Comment: An image of code is not actual code. Please edit your question with the actual code you're using. Something that will make it easier for people to copy/paste in order to try to replicate the issue

Comment: [2019-12-12 11:05:25] local.ERROR: Call to undefined relationship [images] on model [App\Model\Product]. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException(code: 0): Call to undefined relationship [images] on model [App\\Model\\Product]. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\theliquorshop\\tls_api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException.php:34)

Comment: relations are working fine without withDefaults() method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the docs (and what @Hashmat answered)

> The `belongsTo`, `hasOne`, `hasOneThrough`, and `morphOne` relationships allow you to define a default model that will be returned if the given relationship is null

This implies that `hasMany` does not allow `withDefault`. This probably makes sense since `hasMany` would return an empty collection when there are no related models instead of returning null.

Answer (score -1):

The `belongsTo`, `hasOne`, `hasOneThrough`, and `morphOne` relationships allow you to define a default model that will be returned if the given relationship is null. This pattern is often referred to as the Null Object pattern and can help remove conditional checks in your code.

To populate the default model with attributes, you may pass an array or Closure to the withDefault method:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Model')->withDefault([
        'name' => 'Test Image',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I got this point, but this thing isn't working. With default method on images method's hasMany relationship is giving error still.

Comment: What are the default attributes value you want to pass?
And what the error message you're getting?

Comment: [2019-12-12 11:05:25] local.ERROR: Call to undefined relationship [images] on model [App\Model\Product]. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException(code: 0): Call to undefined relationship [images] on model [App\\Model\\Product]. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\theliquorshop\\tls_api\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException.php:34)

Comment: relations are working fine though, without withDefault() method